# How to connect Sql query to Microsoft vb

Tags: vb.net, ssms

I have created a sql query from a table  in [ssms](/questions/tagged/ssms) and I want to run it in vb.

Here is the query I have created.
[image: ssms query]

And I want to run it through the button calculate
and display the `AmtDue` from the ssms query in the label `AmtDue` for a given name in the `combobox`  (Name) in the VB form.

Here is the VB form:
[image: Vb form]

Source code for vb form.

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TryDataSet2.TableTry' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TableTryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TryDataSet2.TableTry)

    End Sub

  Private Sub FillByToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Me.TableTryTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.TryDataSet2.TableTry)
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

  End Sub

  Private Sub ButtonCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCalculate.Click

  End Sub
End Class
```

When i add a query in the "TableTryTableAdapter" and when i run it i got that error message:

> `The schema returned by the new query differs from the base query.`

Comment: Hi Matabadul, Its difficult to help if we don't understand what your problem is. Do you get any error when running this code?

Comment: Hi J. Chomel, Thank you for responding to my question. When i add a query in the "TableTryTableAdapter" and when i run it i got that error message. The schema returned by the new query differs from the base query.